# How to reset the Kudu WebJob dashboard or logging?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, kudu

I'm trying to find details of the function executions of a particular WebJob. Unfortunately the function dashboard in Kudu is showing duplicates, exclamation marks, and no function executions for over two months.

[image: WebJob Function Dashboard]

Trying to use the Azure CLI to list the WebJob's runs gives the error `NotFound`.

The WebJob has been moved to a different web app which could be related.

It doesn't matter if all of the logging history is wiped and everything reset, I would just like this working again! Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just browse the storage account configured for your Azure WebJob Dashboard (using a tool like Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer) and delete the content of azure-jobs-* and azure-webjobs-* containers:

[image: blog containers]

Comment: This took forever and it looks like just deleting the containers might have been OK. Regardless I still had issues, possibly because I had webjobs with the same function name or maybe because of sharing between different deployment slots. I separated everything and wiped these logs and all looks OK now.

Comment: Somehow my jobs broke after removing above 4 containers. Removing + redeploying fixed the issue.

Comment: In my experience this generally just causes the webjobs to fail on startup with a 409 Conflict error.  I find I generally have to delete the entire storage account and recreate it.

Comment: Technically I think Azure takes some time to delete the containers and you just need to wait awhile.

Answer (score 1):

To remove items appearing under `Functions` on the **Web Jobs Dashboard** - just remove the entry in the Azure Storage Blob Table `AzureWebJobsHostLogscommon` corresponding to the `RowKey` matching the name appearing there.

After doing this - the dashboard no longer shows functions that have been removed from this table.